# Javascript Ticker Problem

Tags: javascript

I found a bit of Javascript to create a news ticker—essentially just rotating through the items of a list.

```
<script>
var ticker = $('ul.ticker');
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();
setInterval(function() {
    ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(ticker);
        ticker.children(':first').show();
    });
},5000);
</script>
```

It worked really well when I just had list items, but when I made the list items into links it started acting strangely. I watched it with firebug and it appears that it goes through the list just fine the first time, then starts creating new list items:

```
<li style="display: none;"></li>
```

It seems to alternate displaying one of these `<li>` then after it goes through the list the first time.

Thank you for your help!

edit 1: HTML

```
<ul class="ticker">
<li><a href="#">News Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not Java, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Cool - I could have edited it but I thought I might be missing something. Also, I apologize for the pedantic tone.

Comment: It looks like that code works by pulling out the first `<li>` in the list and then adding it back to the end of the list. The first `<li>` is thus always the visible one. What exactly does your HTML look like?

Comment: Do you wrap links into li? I mean `<li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>` ?

Comment: I've added my HTML to my original post.

Comment: Ok, I though so you wrap them - look down below - that could help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that problem lies in `ticker.find(':visible')`. If your links are wrapped in `li`, then that code finds `li` and `a` inside of it and appending them separately to the ticker. Try `ticker.find('li:visible')`.

**EDIT**: or `ticker.children(':visible')`.